# (Ubuntu 18.04) Music vanished from Nautilus 'Places' left sidebar, config file edit no help

Tags: nautilus, configuration

The entry for the Music folder in my Home directory moved down below "+ Other Locations" in my places panel in Nautilus. When I tried to access it, I got an "OOPS" error message, "Unable to find the requested file. Please try again.". I edited my `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file and found that the Music folder entry was incomplete. Despite repeatedly editing the file, following a reboot or logoff, the file reverts to the incorrect setting. I manually deleted the non-working "Music" link at the bottom of the sidebar, thinking there might be some duplicate entry that was causing a conflict, but this didn't fix the issue either. Below is the file with the incomplete entry:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

As you can see, the location for the "Music" folder is missing. More than 7 times, I've edited the file as follows:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

The edited entry appears in Nautilus after the edit, but when I try to navigate to the Music folder from the sidebar, I get the "Oops! Something went wrong." message. After a reboot or logoff, the Music folder is gone every time. I've looked at the `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` and `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults files`, and both appear to be normal. Here is the output from `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`:

```
DESKTOP=Desktop
DOWNLOAD=Downloads
TEMPLATES=Templates
PUBLICSHARE=Public
DOCUMENTS=Documents
MUSIC=Music
PICTURES=Pictures
VIDEOS=Videos
```

Answer (score 1):

You have most likely moved or deleted your `Music` folder hence the "Unable to find the requested file. Please try again." error message.

On every reboot `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` is updated by `xdg-user-dirs-update`. Quoting `man xdg-user-dirs-update`:

> Additionally, any configured directories that point to non-existing locations are reset by pointing them to the users home directory.

Run `xdg-user-dirs-update --force` to both reset `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` using `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` and to recreate any missing directories to stop this happening again.

It won't fix broken symlinks though, nor help if the symlink is into a partition which isn't mounted at boot.